# Flexbox Container Fitting Content Without Inline

Tags: html, css, flexbox, containers

I have the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CLight/5tm168uk/

As you can see, there's a lot of wasted space in the middle. **How would it be possible to have the container shrink down neatly based on the content, without breaking the recursive structure?** I tried solving this problem using floats, but I got stuck for a few hours trying to deal with the width.

EDIT: To clarify, I'm trying to get it to look like this: [image]

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.recursive {
  padding: 0% 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box left">
    2314
  </div>
  <div class="box right">
    55453
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box recursive">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box left">
        3453535345353535
      </div>
      <div class="box right">
        3534535
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="box recursive">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="box left">
            3453
          </div>
          <div class="box right">
            3
          </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box left">
    4535
  </div>
  <div class="box right">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/5tm168uk/1/

Comment: empty space ... is it not the padding you setted in the CSS ? `.recursive {
  padding: 0% 5%;
}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @IsmailFarooq, I added an image an edit to clarify what I meant.

Comment: Allowed to change the structure ? Its easy makeable if your left and right side is in a seperate container and not in lines linke atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, an inline wrapper solve these issues, where the items are sized based on their content.

In this case would an inline flex container using column direction fix that.

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex
}

.box {
  flex: 1
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px
}

.recursive {
  padding: 0 5vw
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box left">
      2314
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
      55453
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box recursive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box left">
          3453535345353535
        </div>
        <div class="box right">
          3534535
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box recursive">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="box left">
              3453
            </div>
            <div class="box right">
              3
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box left">
      4535
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

To balance it, a minimum width could be helpful.

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 450px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex
}

.box {
  flex: 1
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px
}

.recursive {
  padding: 0 5vw
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box left">
      2314
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
      55453
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box recursive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box left">
          3453535345353535
        </div>
        <div class="box right">
          3534535
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box recursive">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="box left">
              3453
            </div>
            <div class="box right">
              3
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box left">
      4535
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @LGSon. It seems that if a number is long enough, it would overlap with the adjacent column instead of expanding the container. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @user5056973 I will have a look. Question: can the content differ in height as well, where e.g. one of the left/right content could be in 2 lines?

Comment: @user5056973 Question 2: can the markup be altered?

Comment: (1) Unfortunately, I cannot have any line breaks. (2) The markup can be altered as long as there is a recursive component to it. Thanks @LGSon.

Comment: @user5056973 Why the longer push the shorter is that Flexbox items doesn't work as table rows/cells, which grow collectively. There is 3 ways to accomplish what you ask ... 1: using a `table` (which might be good since this is appears to be tabular data) ... 2: change markup and where you instead of start with rows, start with 2 columns, a left and a right ... 3: keep the existing solution and with a script get the widest item and use its width as a minimum width ... so which one do you prefer?

Comment: @user5056973 After some more thoughts, and with the nested structure you have, even with `table` you likely will need a 2 column structure since you want to have that _center line_ horizontally aligned cross left/right content.

Comment: I actually did that using a table and it worked, but for reasons too odd to get into I made the switch to divs. I took out the borders and the layout satisfied the requirement even though the middle column doesn't always align. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look mate. You need wrap with one div for all element so you can handle easily.
I have tried here

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;

}

.container{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.333%;
}

.box{
  flex:1
}

.left{
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px
}

.right{
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px
}


.recursive{
  padding: 0% 5%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box left">
      2314
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
      55453
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box recursive">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box left">
          3453535345353535
        </div>
        <div class="box right">
          3534535
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="box recursive">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box left">
              3453
            </div>
            <div class="box right">
              3
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box left">
      4535
    </div>
    <div class="box right">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tm168uk/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap :

css:

```
 div {
      border: 1px solid black;
      margin: auto;
    }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class=" col-md-6">
    2314
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    55453
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        3453535345353535
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        3534535
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        3453
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    4535
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5tm168uk/8/